# Pass value of datagridview in crystal report or rdlc report

Tags: rdlc, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2008

How can I pass all the value of `datagridview` to `crystal report` or `rdlc report`? I try everything but nothing works `T_T` It's been 3 days since I was finding a solution about this. Can someone please help me.

Comment: @Geroganantanatda you should add some snippet here

Comment: what kind of snippet?

Comment: what you tried to get the solution

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268900-datagridview-to-crystal-report/ - I tried this one but it's not working